# Why did Swami Vivekananda remain unmarried?

Tags: marriage, vivekananda

Swami Vivekananda was a disciple of Ramakrishna Paramahamsa, who was married. Swamiji's take on marriage was also positive:
[What was Swami Vivekananda's take on marriage?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9693/1049)

He was also an avid reader of Gita, which suggests to consider happiness & sorrow as seasons and renounce their effects to attain liberation (BG 2.14-15). A married person surely doesn't have to look elsewhere for happiness & especially sorrow, to be able to create an indifference between them. It becomes easier. :-)

Did Vivekananda ever mention reasons for not getting married himself?

Comment: Ramakrishna didn't have the urge to be married. It was just the customs of his family and the time in which he lived, for early marriage. He remained celibate even after marriage. He preferred disciples who were untouched by Kama (i.e. before they became gruhastha). Vivekananda, being chief disciple was special case. I believe I read in either Kathamrita or Complete Works - "the boy touched by kama is like the vessel touched by garlic, no matter how much you clean it, a vasana still lingers". For spreading the word of his guru, he could not be fettered by family.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swamiji was not interested in marriage from early age. When asks in interview he says he see Divine Mother in every woman.  He says it in [Volume 3](http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_3/vol_3_frame.htm), Reports in American Newspapers, Hindus at the Fair, Complete works.

> "Why should I marry," was his abrupt response to a comment on all he
>   had renounced in becoming a monk, "**when I see in every woman only
>   the divine Mother?** Why do I make all these sacrifices? To emancipate
>   myself from earthly ties and attachments so that there will be no
>   re-birth for me. When I die I want to become at once absorbed in the
>   divine, one with God. I would be a Buddha."

In his early age, Swamiji's father thought to marry him and he  even tried to convince Narendranath (Swamiji's pre-monastic name) when his father got a offer of 10,000 Indian rupees as dowry but Swamiji rejected.

*Gopal Shrinivas Banhatti*, in his book *Life And Philosophy Of Swami Vivekananda*, says:

> **His resolve not to marry was the perceptible outcome of his stern idea
>   of purity.** Even before he appeared for the B.A. examination, offers
>   for marriage poured in. An alluring proposal of a dowry enough to
>   finance his education in England leading to the I.C.S. examination was
>   summarily rejected by him. Indeed Vivekananda was to visit England for
>   another purpose to educate Englishmen.

Swamiji thought his Guru Ramakrishna's strong will to prepare him for his Guru's works was the reason for these failures.

**Additional Reference**:[Did Swami Vivekananda marry? on Swamivivekanandaquotes.org](http://www.swamivivekanandaquotes.org/2014/05/did-swami-vivekananda-get-married.html)